# PHP Scripts Encapsulating Returned JSON Array with Number Above and Number Below

Tags: php, json, echo

I'm having a problem where my PHP scripts are returning my json encoded array with a number above and a number below it. Like follows:

```
26

[0,"edited_token_string"]

0
```

I have not changed any of the scripts that I'm encountering this on, but it is happening with all of them. I don't have any other echos other than the one used to echo the array. Our server was returning "null" from all of the scripts all morning and now is returning the correct array, with these numbers surrounding it. Is it possible something was updated on the server that accidentally turned on some type of debugging? I've called our hosting service, but they are incredibly unhelpful.

Thanks in advance,

Max

Comment: maybe provide your script? create an empty test.php and execute it. do you still get output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `header('Content-type: application/json');` directly above the line that outputs your JSON. If something else has already outputted something, you will get an error telling you where in your code that happened.

For the undesired output after the JSON, could it be that there is also an extra space after the closing `?>` tag? A quick and dirty fix would be to just add `die;` after the last intentional echo;

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan! That helped with the number at the front which looks like was caused by an inadvertent space before the <? At the beginning of an include file. I'm still getting a zero after the returned array. If I edit out the following line: echo json_encode($return_array); then the 0 goes away at the end and null is returned. This is really odd... Thanks again for the help

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan. I looked for an inadvertent space after the closing ?>, but no luck. I also added the die; after the echo statement, but am still getting the zero after the returned array. I recently added cocoa pods to my Xcode project, but didn't add AFNetworking using them, so I would think it shouldn't affect this library.